# Retrieving Data from Elasticsearch-SQL CLI - Insert into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch 6.7 which has an Elasticsearch SQL cli. This allows me to run more standard SQL queries. This is preferred over the API method as the query capabilities are much more robust.

I am attempting to run a query through this CLI and insert those results into a pandas data frame. Is this something I can do via the subprocess method or is there an easier/better way. This will go into production so it needs to run on multiple environments.

This python program will be running on a different host than the Elasticsearch machine.

Comment: It looks like elastic is updating their python library to use SQL, however, it is not out yet and I have no clue when it will be released; hopefully with production release of 7.0